# Removing elements that are multiples of 4 from a matrix in R

Tags: r

This code is supposed to remove all mutiples of 4 from the given vector, when I run it, only 8 gets removed.

```
multipleoffour<- function(y){
y2<-y
for (n in y )
{if (n%%4==0)
y2<-y2[-n]
}
return (y2)  
}
```

multipleoffour(c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14))

Comment: Why not simply use `my_vec[my_vec %% 4 != 0]` for `my_vec <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14)`?

Answer (score 0):

Since R is vectorized this is more of an R way to do this:

```
multipleoffour<- function(y){

    y[y %% 4 != 0]
}

multipleoffour(c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14))
## [1]  2  6 10 14
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code doesn't work is because `y2<-y2[-n]` remove the nth element of the vector and not n itself. In your example it removed 8, which is the 4th element of your vector. Otherwise, I agree with other answers about how to do it more efficiently.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).